# Unable to retrieve a list from a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do something extremely simple, and am having difficulty.
I have a CSV file with time (t) and temperature (T) values (there are only two columns).
I can retrieve the times t in the form of a list using .tolist(), but the temperatures will not convert to a list, as I get this error: KeyError: 'T'.

This is my code:

```
time_vals = pd.read_csv('Temperature.csv')
print(time_vals['t'].tolist())
print(time_vals['T'].tolist()).
```

The CSV file as shown in an image:

[image]

Comment: You can check the exact name of the columns by using `time_vals.columns`. Sometime the column names get an additional character while importing from csv (specially if the csv is manually created).
Hope it helps.

Comment: @gaurav There was a space in front of T for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

> There was a space in front of T for some reason

As you have only 2 columns, you can force the name of the headers instead of modify your file(s):

```
# You can also use cols=['time', 'Temp'] or whatever you want
time_vals = pd.read_csv('Temperature.csv', header=0, cols=['t', 'T'])
print(time_vals['t'].tolist())
print(time_vals['T'].tolist())
```